# While loop using zend and mysql

Tags: zend-framework

rowI'm new at zend, so please be patient :).

I need to extract only 5 results from a mysql query, how can I do this loop to work?, I'll try to explain myself:

```
$var = $db->query($sql);
while($rows = $var->fetch()) {
$msg = 'loop from 1 to 5';
}
return $this->view->msg = $msg;
```

Hope you guys understand my issue, I know already the sentences are not correct written, but making myself understandable, please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this might help get you on your way?

```
$var = $db->query($sql);
for($i = 0; $i<5; $i++) {
   $row = $var->fetch()) {
   $msg = 'loop from 1 to 5';
}
return $this->view->msg = $msg;
```

Comment: Nope it shows me just one result :(, what I did was adding while before $row and closed {}, but still thorws me just one result

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning more than one result? Maybe you need to debug your query first.

Comment: Like I saud I'm newbie ate zend I thought the while argument will allow me to retrieve more than one, but I guess I'm wrong, how then can I retrieve more than one result? chekc the zend guide, it syas fetch is a loop http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html

Comment: I did it, I used fetchAll($sql) and returned each valur using the array option: $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bugs');
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo $rows[0]['bug_description']; as it says in zend guide http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html. Many thanks

Comment: You code is non well formed, it has two opening `{`, but only one closing `}`. Plus, it will likely fail when there are less than `5` results available. I recommend using `LIMIT 5` in the `SQL` statement. Then you can actuall use `fetchAll`, too.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `LIMIT 5` in your SQL statement. That is much more performant when you tell the SQL server you only need 5 results. Otherwise, you probably run into a null exception when there are just 4, for example.